# The terminal process command failed to launch exit code:0 and exit code:2

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

The visual studio code terminal is not working.
The shortcut `ctrl+"` for the terminal is not working.

Error:

```
The terminal process terminated with exit code: {0}
```

The terminal process command

```
'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' failed to launch (exit code: {2})
```

[image]

Comment: Can you launch Powershell normally outside of VS Code? Did you configure any [terminal options/args](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration) for Powershell?

Comment: Your image says "System32\cmd.exe" but you also said "powershell.exe". Which is it?

Comment: yeap powershell and cmd.exe outside working probably bitdefender blocked

Comment: my business use bitdefender endpoint security tools. i do bitdefender disable its run

Comment: I just uninstall the powershell and reinstall it. It perfectly worked.

Answer (score 5):

**Try creating an exception rule for winpty-agent.exe in you antivirus program.**

```
File location: 

C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar.unpacked\node-pty\build\Release\winpty-agent.exe
```

If first solution doesnt work for you, you can try to create exception rule for the whole folder where winpty-agent.exe is stored => "realese"

```
Folder location: 

C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar.unpacked\node-pty\build\Release
```

**Update 21.3.2020**
I also had to make an exception in malwarebytes for winpty-agent.exe in appdata/local

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar.unpacked\node-pty\build\Release\winpty-agent.exe
```

Comment: It fixes the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @MrHIDEn which antivirus program are you using ?

Comment: @strix25 Malwarebytes and McAfee, but my company disabled any access to them. I asked them but thay did nothing. For some unknown reason sometimes after a couple of hours terminal is working as a charm. No idea why after reboot it does not work but later it can works. ?

Comment: @strix25 I hope there is other solution

Comment: @MrHIDEn Malwarebytes was blocking it for me. :) Myb talk with your dev ops guy if he can add it, if they dont want to give you access :P

Answer (score 2):

Vscode terminal currently does not work with the program Malwarebytes.  You will have to uninstall until a fix is made.  Antivirus related software seems to be the main culprit.

Comment: Can confirm that Malwarebytes was the culprit on my system - I did not have to uninstall though, simply quit from the system tray

Comment: Same here, can confirm.  Added ...\winpty-agent.exe to the Allow List, and I am golden!

Comment: But I can not stop, remove Malwarebytes as it is locked by my company. I can not add rule to that. Teminal sometimes works and sometimes not. For now VSC is piece of crap without terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. For me it helped to start VS code as admin...
I'm on a semi-enterprise IT-controlled environment.

Comment: Yes, I got the same issue, working on a client Laptop; I ran VScode as an admin and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I excluded  "Microsoft VS Code" folder from ransomware detection, and now I can open a terminal window.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Use 'cmd.exe' instead of 'powershell.exe' by following these steps here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59416769/2015398

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl + shift + p then the command palette will open.
then paste this on the box

```
Terminal: Select Default Profile
```

press enter, then choose cmd from the list.

Answer (score -1):

I've recently ran into the same issue while setting up a new web development environment (not just bash but any terminal).  For me, I just had to set VS Code to run as administrator and then bam, no problem accessing the command line executable.