# How do I change my VS Code terminal to cmd.exe instead of powershell?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

For some reason my VS Code terminal is Powershell instead of cmd.exe.  In my Terminal > External: Windows Exec is set to C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe.  However, when I open the Terminal in VS Code I see PS C:...>.  Also, in the terminal drop-down I only see powershell as an option.

How do I switch the Terminal to CMD.exe? Or maybe my better option would be to add cmd.exe to the list of available terminals so I can switch between them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Open File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. Select User Settings in upper right corner.
3. Add the following line

   ```
   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe"
   ```

   Source: https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/02/vs-code-integrated-terminal-powershell-default-change-to-cmd/

Comment: This is now deprecated.

Answer (score 23):

**To version**

[image]

First step:

[image]

Second step: select the desired option:

[image]

Or

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
```

Answer (score 5):

To add onto LeSchlongLong's answer, which is now deprecated, you can simply follow these steps to change the default profile:

1. Ctrl+Shift+P (Windows) / Cmd+Shift+P (Mac)
2. Search for "Terminal: Select Default Profile"

   [image: command search]
3. Select whichever profile you would like to use

   [image: select default profile]

Answer (score 1):

You can use View / Command Palete / Terminal: select default terminal to select from the range of detected terminals. Mine shows PS and cmd.exe which had to be changed as PS is disabled as a security policy in our environment.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent VS Code upgrade the command prompt path in the profile config was updated as well -  terminal.integrated.profiles.windows

This article mentioned how you can reset that.

https://dev.to/andrewriveradev/how-to-set-git-bash-as-integrated-terminal-in-vscode-2k31

1. Open command palette (CMD + Shift + P)
2. Search "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)"
3. Delete the terminal.integrated.profiles.windows object from the config
4. Create a new field by typing "" (double quotation key). Inside the quotation type "terminal." a list of options will appear.
5. Select terminal.integrated.profiles.windows. When you select terminal.integrated.profiles.windows it will be expanded
6. Add or replace "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe"