# Error Configuring Flutter With PowerShell In VS Code

Tags: powershell, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am getting the following error when executing `flutter doctor` command in PowerShell:

```
Program 'flutter' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation.
```

I have already set the environment variable for Flutter/bin, Git and Windows/System32.

Flutter commands work fine on normal cmd, but not in PowerShell which is the default in VS Code.

How to fix this?

Comment: have you tried dotsourcing your executable while in powershell? e.g. `PS C:\> .\flutter.exe docter`

Comment: @DustyVargas Thanks, I tried it does not work, I guess it is related to the installed version of PS.

Comment: I ended up changing the default editor in VS Code to Command Prompt, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59416769/3408531 .

Comment: Ah I see. I have also had various issues with the powershell embedded terminal in vscode. I've heard that the preview version is better but who knows. I just keep a pwsh window up while I work.