# VSCode terminal not open (exit code : 3221225794)

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open terminal in VSCode, i saw this error and not open terminal tab.

The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: 3221225794.

Answer (score -2):

These are the solutions I have found from my research

**1st** Option:

Run VS Code as aadministrator

**2nd** Option:

Configure [terminal options/args](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows) for Powershell

**3rd** Option:

Please check the following link, this link provide some VS Code trouble shooting steps
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch

**4th** Option:

Use 'cmd.exe' instead of 'powershell.exe' by following these steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59416769/2015398